# Is there a way to use a TinyMCE configuration file instead tinymce.init()?

Tags: tinymce-5

I have to load the TinyMCE configuration in every page where it is used. Is there a chance to load the configuration once in the whole website instead to load a lot of rows of configuration commands in every page as the following code:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: true,
    dialog_type: 'modal',
    fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
    font_formats: "Arial=arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" +
        "Arial Black=arial black,avant garde;" +
        "Courier New=courier new,courier;" +
        "Georgia=georgia,palatino;" +
        "Helvetica=helvetica;" +
        "Symbol=symbol;" +
        "Times New Roman=times new roman,times;" +
        "Trebuchet MS=trebuchet ms,geneva;",
    referrer_policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin',
    plugins: 'print, code, lists, table, paste',
        paste_as_text: true,
    height: 400,
    language: 'it',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | fontselect fontsizeselect styleselect bold italic alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | table tabledelete | tableprops tablerowprops tablecellprops | tableinsertrowbefore tableinsertrowafter tabledeleterow | tableinsertcolbefore tableinsertcolafter tabledeletecol | bullist numlist outdent indent code',
    formats: {
        alignleft: {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'left', styles : {'text-indent': '50px'}},
        aligncenter: {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'center', styles : {'text-indent': '50px'}},
        alignright: {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'right', styles : {'text-indent': '50px'}},
        alignjustify: {selector : 'p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,td,th,div,ul,ol,li,table,img', classes : 'full', styles : {'text-indent': '50px', 'text-align': 'justify'}}
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance and regards!
Manugi

Comment: I forgot: TintMCE is loaded via CDN, not self hosted.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with the following code:

```
$.getScript("js/tinymce.config.js", function() {
    //do something if necessary
});
```

where the file tinymce.config.js contains:

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea',
    menubar: true,
    dialog_type: 'modal',
    fontsize_formats: "8pt 10pt 12pt 14pt 18pt 24pt 36pt",
    ....
});
```